# frame option from adjustbox does not work in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, adjustbox

This MWE works in pdf. It puts frame around an image. But in HTML I see no frame produces

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}%for frame option
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,frame=0.1in]{A.png}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using `lualatex foo4.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But compiled using `make4ht foo4.tex` gives this. No frame and some scratch line at bottom right corner

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Source code produced looks wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta  charset="iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo4.css" /> 
<meta name="src" content="foo4.tex" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" > <img 
src="A.png" alt="PIC"  
 />_
     __
</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

I know I can use `fbox` to put a frame around an image and this works in tex4ht:

```
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.png}}
```

but I wanted to use `frame` instead for other purposes. I could always use `fbox` in tex4ht mode and use `frame` in pdf mode. So I have a workaround for this, but was hoping to avoid this complication and use same code for both if possible.

Is there a way to make `frame` work in tex4ht also?

ps. I could not use the example images that come with latex for the MWE above, since these do not work with tex4ht for some reason. Path issue it seem, so I used my own image. Here is copy of `A.png` if you need to use it or any other image can be used.

https://www.12000.org/tmp/051119/A.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this version of `adjustbox.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignTop}{1}
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignMiddle}{1}
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignCenter}{1}
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignBottom}{1}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@t{\a:AdjustboxValignTop}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@t{\a:AdjustboxValignTop}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@T{\a:AdjustboxValignTop}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@M{\a:AdjustboxValignMiddle}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@m{\a:AdjustboxValignMiddle}
\pend:defI\adjbox@valign@c{\a:AdjustboxValignCenter}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@b{\a:AdjustboxValignBottom}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@B{\a:AdjustboxValignBottom}

% make an unique ID for each adjustbox environment
\newcounter{adjustbox@4ht}
\def\update:adjustbox:id{\stepcounter{adjustbox@4ht}\def\AdjustboxId{adjustbox-\arabic{adjustbox@4ht}}}

\NewConfigure{Adjustbox}{2}
\def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{\update:adjustbox:id\a:Adjustbox\o:adjbox@@frame:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\b:Adjustbox}
\HLet\adjbox@@frame\:tempa

% suppress trying to draw the frame
\def\adjbox@boxframe#1#2#3{}

% we should redefine all adjustbox environments, they may produce unvanted artifacts, math mode, etc.
% keys are set, so it should be possible to extract  colors or frame size in theory
% I just haven't found a working solution yet
\renewenvironment{adjustbox}[1]{\update:adjustbox:id\adjbox@setkeys{#1}\a:Adjustbox}{\b:Adjustbox}

% definitions for macros
% we don't save any colors and just use one configuration for all box types.  
\def\@bgcolorbox#1{\update:adjustbox:id\a:Adjustbox\BOXCONTENT\b:Adjustbox}
\def\@foregroundbox#1#2#3{\update:adjustbox:id\leavevmode\a:Adjustbox\BOXCONTENT\b:Adjustbox}
\def\@backgroundbox#1#2#3{\update:adjustbox:id\leavevmode\a:Adjustbox\BOXCONTENT\b:Adjustbox}

\Hinput{adjustbox}
```

It generates unique ID for each adjust box, so it can be then styled using CSS. The configuration can look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{halignTR}{}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignTop}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:top;}}}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignMiddle}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:middle;}}}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignCenter}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:middle;}}}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignBottom}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:bottom;}}}
\makeatletter
\def\pttoem#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr#1/\f@size em}
\Configure{Adjustbox}
 {\IgnorePar\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{<div class="adjustbox" id="\AdjustboxId">}}
 {\Css{\#\AdjustboxId{border: \pttoem{\fboxrule} solid black;padding: \pttoem{\fboxsep};}}\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The interesting part is this:

```
\def\pttoem#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr#1/\f@size em}
\Configure{Adjustbox}
 {\IgnorePar\EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{<div class="adjustbox" id="\AdjustboxId">}}
 {\Css{\#\AdjustboxId{border: \pttoem{\fboxrule} solid black;padding: \pttoem{\fboxsep};}}\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
```

It defines command `\pttoem` that converts TeX dimensions  to `em`, because it is better to use relative units in CSS. `<div class="adjustbox">` with unique ID from `\AdjusboxID` is constructed for each adjustbox. CSS with border size and padding is created for each box.

This is the result:

[image]